# Opengl ES 2.0 Depth test doesn't work properly

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, depth

I'm trying to learn OpenGL ES 2.0 and I went to load 3d models on Android. I can now load properly with the model texture, but I have a problem on the display depth. When I place my model in perspective, and part of the model is hidden by another part of it, it happens to me that a triangle or two before another draw and this is what I see through some parts .

I try setEGLConfigChooser (8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0); and (8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 0), but my problem remains the same, except that when I put (8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 0) and display a little better defined, but when the 3d object moves, the colors make a strobe effect that is disturbing to me.

I also try glDepthFunc function (GL_LEQUAL); with glEnable (GL_DEPTH_TEST), but this does not rule over my problem.

Here's the pictures of the probleme:

The probleme : Link is broken

The good : Link is broken

Sorry for my link picture, I do not have more than 10 reputation to post picture in the question.

Here my code
My GLSurfaceView

```
public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;

    setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
    setEGLConfigChooser(true);

    //setZOrderOnTop(true);
    //setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 16, 0);
    //setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 0);
    //getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    mRenderer = new Renderer(context);
    setRenderer(mRenderer);
}
```

My renderer

```
 @Override
 public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);  
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glFrontFace(GL_CCW);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    mushroom = new Mushroom();

    textureProgram = new TextureShaderProgram(context);
    texture = TextureHelper.loadTexture(context, R.drawable.mushroom);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {                
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    MatrixHelper.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix, 45, (float) width
            / (float) height, 0f, 10f);
    setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, 0f, 1.2f, -10.2f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f);
}

@Override    
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    multiplyMM(viewProjectionMatrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0);

    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
    //glDepthMask(true);

    positionMushroomInScene();
    textureProgram.useProgram();
    textureProgram.setUniforms(modelViewProjectionMatrix, texture);
    mushroom.bindData(textureProgram);

    mushroom.draw();
    //glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);
}

private void positionMushroomInScene() {
    setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
    translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0f, 0f, 5f);
    rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, -yRotation, 1f, 0f, 0f);
    rotateM(modelMatrix, 0, xRotation, 0f, 1f, 0f);
    multiplyMM(modelViewProjectionMatrix, 0, viewProjectionMatrix,
            0, modelMatrix, 0);
}
```

My matrix Helper

```
public static void perspectiveM(float[] m, float yFovInDegrees, float aspect, float n, float f) {
    final float angleInRadians = (float) (yFovInDegrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
    final float a = (float) (1.0 / Math.tan(angleInRadians / 2.0));

    m[0] = a / aspect;
    m[1] = 0f;
    m[2] = 0f;
    m[3] = 0f;
    m[4] = 0f;
    m[5] = a;
    m[6] = 0f;
    m[7] = 0f;
    m[8] = 0f;
    m[9] = 0f;
    m[10] = -((f + n) / (f - n));
    m[11] = -1f;
    m[12] = 0f;
    m[13] = 0f;
    m[14] = -((2f * f * n) / (f - n));
    m[15] = 0f;
}
```

Comment: doesn't look like a depth test issue at all. Might be just clipping, but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely with the way you set up your projection matrix:

```
MatrixHelper.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix, 45, (float) width
        / (float) height, 0f, 10f);
```

The 4th argument in your definition of this function is the near plane. This value should never be 0.0. It should typically be a reasonable fraction of the far distance. Choosing the ideal value can be somewhat of a tradeoff. The larger `far / near` is, the less depth precision you get. On the other hand, if you set the `near` value too large, you risk clipping off close geometry that you actually wanted to see.

A ratio of maybe 100 or 1000 for `far / near` should normally give you reasonable depth precision, without undesirable front clipping. You'll need to be a little more conservative with the ratio if you use a 16-bit depth buffer than if you have a 24-bit depth buffer.

For your purpose, try changing `near` to 0.1, and see how that works for you:

```
MatrixHelper.perspectiveM(projectionMatrix, 45, (float) width
        / (float) height, 0.1f, 10f);
```